# no wlan0, Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a hp nx7400 installed with Xubuntu 11.10.

Somehow the wireless does not work, I have read a lot of articles about this but I think I broke more then fixed thinks.

When I do `sudo lshw -C network`, it returns:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:84000000-84000fff memory:84001000-8400100f
```

So I am lost and need help, any help is appreciated.

Comment: this is affecting me as well. Since updating from 12.04 to 14.04

Answer (score 1):

With "PRO/Wireless 3945ABG" not working, it's probably just off. Look for a physical switch or button, or key combination to turn it on. That particular card should work out of the box in Linux.

If you can not find the button, please post the output of `rfkill list all`.

Comment: Yes, was the first thing i thought also but, i can clearly see the blue led turned on and turning it off does not make any difference.

Comment: Also when i turn it off the bluetooth symbool disappears and appears when i turn it on.

Comment: In this case, you'll need to post some more info. Let's see the outputs of `lsmod` and `rfkill list all`. Post the outputs to http://pastebin.com and the links here.

Comment: Ok, thanks fo ryour help here is the link with the output from the commands. http://pastebin.com/D6TMh4aM

Comment: this is affecting me as well. Since updating from 12.04 to 14.04 my wireless is dead. I can only see half the usual networks. I've been playing around with installing different kernels and messing with my kernel modules and black lists but no go. what the bleeping explicative happened. The only thing I have not done yet is roll back to the 12.04 kernel as that would be an extremely disappointing move I want to save for a last resort.